# Can I make hot corners require a mouse click to be triggered?

Tags: mission-control

I love the "Hot corners" concept. However, it happens very often that I trigger them accidentally.

Is there a built-in way to add a "click" requirement to a hot corner? ie. I have to move the mouse there and then to left-click.

(This would also help recreate Windows 7's "show desktop" behaviour, which is cool for people who recently switched from there to OS X.)

Answer (score 6):

### Modifier Keys

or *keyboard* click ;)

You can hold <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>⇧</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd> when selecting a hot corner.

You will need then to use the modifier key and the hot corner to trigger the action.

[image]

### **[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/)**

While you cannot use hot corners, you can use a single finger gesture like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks gentmatt. A mouse-only method would be ideal, but I can work with this if that is not possible.

Comment: @Pekka Maybe BetterTouchTool helps. It's not an optimum solution and without hot corners.

Comment: Beat me to it! While I was writing my answer (and rebooting because BetterTouchTool was acting odd), you wrote a much better one. Well done!

Comment: The corner click in BetterTouchTool seems to apply to the Trackpad only (ie. no mouse clicking, which is a shame! I'll write to the author and ask whether that could be added). But it's a very interesting tool either way. Thanks!